# npm start doesn't work, node index does, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js

This has become very frustrating and it is very simple, no dependencies .
[Visual Studio Code screen shot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA6Bs.png)

can anyone point me in the right direction (npm version shown, Linux version shown )

Comment: don't paste screenshots, please include the error in the text of your post.

Comment: package.json and index.js are in the same directory ?

Comment: First post, sorry for screen shot.. However No errors generated.Also this would just look like a similar question otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, but, yes the package.json is in the same directory

Comment: The issue appears to be with debian/linux as this works fine in windows!! I assume there are some extra settings in this environment that I do not know about yet... any help here please

Answer (score 0):

the command you should execute is as follows:

```
npm run start
```

Comment: Thanks, but the "run" is optional for start, and does not work either

Comment: As per screen shot.. nothing

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
The default in configuration is ... annoying! 
For this to work :
`npm config edit` .. and change
 ignore-scripts from true to false
I hope this helps someone else